# os.walk() caching/speeding up

Tags: python, database, nosql, embedded-database

I have a prototype server[0] that's doing an `os.walk()`[1] for each query a client[0] makes.

I'm currently looking into ways of:

- caching this data in memory,
- speeding up queries, and
- hopefully allowing for expansion into storing metadata and data persistence later on.

I find SQL [complicated](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) for tree structures, so I thought I would get some advice before actually committing to SQLite

Are there any cross-platform, embeddable or bundle-able non-SQL databases that might be able to handle this kind of data?

- I have a small (10k-100k files) list.
- I have an extremely small amount of connections (maybe 10-20).
- I want to be able to scale to handling metadata as well.

[0] the server and client are actually the same piece of software, this is a P2P application, that's designed to share files over a local trusted network with out a main server, using `zeroconf` for discovery, and twisted for pretty much everything else

[1] query time is currently 1.2s with `os.walk()` on 10,000 files

Here is the related function in my Python code that does the walking:

```
def populate(self, string):
    for name, sharedir in self.sharedirs.items():
        for root, dirs, files, in os.walk(sharedir):
            for dir in dirs:
                if fnmatch.fnmatch(dir, string):
                    yield os.path.join(name, *os.path.join(root, dir)[len(sharedir):].split("/"))
            for file in files:
                if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, string): 
                    yield os.path.join(name, *os.path.join(root, ile)[len(sharedir):].split("/"))
```

Comment: Do you have a small number of similar requests by different clients or do you have a lot of variation? In the first case it might make sense to just cache the answer for each request

Comment: And in case you don't know about it: There is an implementation of libfam for python, allowing you to cache the structure without risking it getting out of date

Comment: thanks data I've updated my post to reflect your question, (extremely small amount of connections of maybe 10-20), and I'll look up on libfam as well thanks

Comment: libfm doesn't look cross-platform

Comment: This [StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417917/alternatives-to-sqlite) seems to be looking for something similar. The answers may be of some use.

Comment: When you profiled your application, what was the slow-down?   Please provide the profile results.

Comment: data: I'm expecting variation, the query is just a search filter of the files (sorry didn't read your question properly)

Comment: s.Lott: I wrapped the os.walk for loop with time.time stamps and I got 1148-1219ms I never planed on using this for each query I just needed a prototype

Comment: @Daniel Hill: That's not profile data.  That's elapsed time.  I'm sure it's taking a long time.  The question is "is os.walk the culprit?"  If you're doing some kind of search on 10,000 files, the os.walk is unlikely to be relevant.  10,000 file opens is a far, far bigger issue than os.walk.  I think you should be describing your **real** problem and forgetting about `os.walk`.

Comment: S.Lott I'll paste the function that's called when I search the os.walk tree as you'll see I'm not opening any files, sorry I don't want to learn a profiling tool until I have something actually worth testing

Comment: @Daniel Hill: Until you profile, you're probably wasting time optimizing `os.walk`.  Also.  Why are you yielding directories co-mingled with files?  That seems to be a huge time-waster.

Comment: @S.Lott: http://gist.github.com/543148
as I said it's a prototype everything is subject to change, I never planned on keeping this function

Comment: @Daniel Hill: "it's a prototype"?  So?  Without a profile, there's no reason to optimize os.walk.

Comment: @S.Lott: I provided a profile in that link, as you see the posix.stat is the slow part of the program which is part of os.walk

Comment: @Daniel Hill: "that link"?  Why isn't it part of the question?

Comment: Why are you yielding directories co-mingled with files? That seems to be a huge time-waster.

Comment: if I want to match a folder name I must match it against the folder name as well, unless you have a better idea? (i don't want to match against the dir of the files because that'll return the entire subtree I just want the the folder it's self)

as for the "prototype" maybe I should have used the words "proof of concept"

Comment: @Daniel: A folder is not a file.  The two have essentially nothing to do with each other.  I don't get how you can claim matching a folder is anything like matching a file.  You can't process them in a similar way.  How are they similar?

Comment: I said matching the *name* this is one of the few things that files and folders have in common, and Currently working with **only** the names for my search as I said metadata is coming *later*, I'll Refactor it then, if you would like to provide an better way of doing it please do

Comment: @Daniel: I can't provide a better way because I don't understand what you're doing now.  I don't search "City Names" and "Movies"  in the search search.  It can't be meaningful.  Similarly, searching "Folders" and "File Names" in a single search can't possibly **mean** anything.  So, I can't propose an alternative because your summary (and your code) aren't meaningful.  I can only ask for clarification.

Comment: @S.Lott: If I have a directory structure *Music/<Artist>/<Album>/<#> - <title>.oga* if I search for *foobar* it'll find all files with *foobar* as *<title>* or all folders with the name *<Artist>* or *<Album>*. my code won't return anything If the user tries to search for *both* folder names and file names, I have no way of telling the difference (since the function is only passed a single string). on second thought this is a bad idea all together, if I wanted to search for a particular artist's song with a certain name it won't return anything

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to persist a tree structure -- in fact, your code is busily *dismantling* the natural tree structure of the directory tree into a linear sequence, so why would you want to restart from a tree next time?

Looks like what you need is just an ordered sequence:

```
i   X    result of os.path.join for X
```

where X, a string, names either a file or directory (you treat them just the same), i is a progressively incrementing integer number (to preserve the order), and the result column, also a string, is the result of `os.path.join(name, *os.path.join(root,` &c.

This is perfectly easy to put in a SQL table, of course!

To create the table the first time, just remove the guards `if fnmatch.fnmatch` (and the `string` argument) from your populate function, yield the dir or file before the os.path.join result, and use a `cursor.executemany` to save the `enumerate` of the call (or, use a self-incrementing column, your pick).  To use the table, `populate` becomes essentially a:

```
select result from thetable where X LIKE '%foo%' order by i
```

where `string` is `foo`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how would you say modify the a directory? so all the children are modified to?

Comment: @Daniel, sorry, this new question out of the blue seems to have nothing to do with your original one -- and I have no idea what you mean (and there's hardly space to clarify in comments -- no code, etc).  Why not close this one question that I answered and open another for your new, different issue?  "One question per question" seems a wise and sane policy to me.

Comment: sorry maybe I needed to clarify, Your provided a data structure and a way of adding data to the structure. but I see problems updating the data, when specifically when a Directory is renamed  or moved you'll have to go through the entire structure and match(using LIKE) on column 3 for each file in that directory then update it compared with the first example in the link I provided which would only require a single node to be changed. I just wanted your take on this problem?

Comment: @Daniel, if prefix `/a/b/c/` is renamed to `/a/b/d/`, `UPDATE thetable SET X='/a/b/d/'||SUBSTR(X,8)' WHERE X LIKE '/a/b/c/%'` is the general SQL solution. If you know there are no homonym dicts or subtrees, `SET X=REPLACE(X,'/a/b/c/','/a/b/d/')` or even just `SET X=REPLACE(X,'/c/','/d/')` might suffice, depending on what homonyms (if any) you may rule out.

Answer (score 3):

I misunderstood the question at first, but I think I have a solution now (and sufficiently different from my other answer to warrant a new one).  Basically, you do the normal query the first time you run walk on a directory, but you store the yielded values.  The second time around, you just yield those stored values.  I've wrapped the os.walk() call because it's short, but you could just as easily wrap your generator as a whole.

```
cache = {}
def os_walk_cache( dir ):
   if dir in cache:
      for x in cache[ dir ]:
         yield x
   else:
      cache[ dir ]    = []
      for x in os.walk( dir ):
         cache[ dir ].append( x )
         yield x
   raise StopIteration()
```

I'm not sure of your memory requirements, but you may want to consider periodically cleaning out `cache`.

Comment: well the use-case would only have 1-10 very large directories
not sure if a directory tree would actually take much memory though, that's why I was considering a database engine because it'll take care of the optimizing of memory plus persistence when i need it

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/)?  What about [`mod_python`](http://www.modpython.org/)?  `mod_python` should allow you to do your `os.walk()` and just store the data in Python data structures, since the script is persistent between connections.

Comment: is MongoDB easily bundle-able?, sorry I'm not sure why you're suggesting mod_python? isn't that limited to HTTP?